# Reducing PyInstaller Executable Size When Excluding Standard Libraries

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to create a standalone executable using PyInstaller for a Python script, and I've noticed that when I use the --exclude-all option to exclude standard libraries, the size of the generated executable becomes larger compared to when I don't exclude any libraries.

Here's the command I used:

```
pyinstaller hello.py --onefile --exclude-module _abc --exclude-module _ast --exclude-module _codecs --exclude-module _io --exclude-module _json --exclude-module _locale --exclude-module _opcode --exclude-module _pickle --exclude-module _signal --exclude-module _sre --exclude-module _symtable --exclude-module _tracemalloc --exclude-module _warnings --exclude-module _weakref
```

The resulting executable is much larger than expected (23 MB), whereas the default command without exclusion produces a smaller file (8 MB):

```
pyinstaller hello.py --onefile
```

Is there a more effective way to reduce the size of the PyInstaller executable when excluding standard libraries? Are there specific modules that I should exclude or include to achieve a smaller size without compromising functionality?